# Delete file in 59 intervals

Tags: file, sorting, batch-file, vbscript, delete-file

I have 12468 Files and I only need every 60th one.

How do I (Batch file Hopefully) Delete 59 files, Skip one, delete 59 more, delete one etc or another way to do this effectually.

File Examples: sequence_00001.jpg, sequence_00002.jpg, ---- sequence 12468.jpg etc...

Comment: What does this have to do with JavaScript?

Comment: Would need examples of the file names.  Files do not sort the same in batch files as they do in Windows Explorer.

Comment: sequence_xxxxx.jpg

Comment: `set i=0 & for %%a in (*.jpg) do (set /A "i=(i+1)%%60" & if !i! neq 0 del %%a)`

Comment: post as answer and will select has Best. Is this VBS or Batch?

Comment: Is the `xxxxx` portion always exactly five digits long?

Comment: @epicdig07, I asked for examples.  PLURAL.  Meaning more than one. Update your question with that information.

Comment: @Squashman Edited!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Batch code delete 59 files and keep the 60th one, and so on. The files are processed *in the same order of `dir` command* (that is the same order of plain `for` command), independently of the file name format:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set i=0
for %%a in (*.jpg) do (
   set /A "i=(i+1)%%60"
   if !i! neq 0 del "%%a"
)
```

This Batch code process files with this format: `sequence_00001.jpg`, `sequence_00002.jpg`, etc. and keep files whose 5 last digits part is multiple of 60; deletes the rest:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /F "tokens=1,2* delims=_." %%a in ('dir /A-D /B sequence_*.jpg') do (
   set /A "i=(1%%b-100000)%%60"
   if !i! neq 0 del "%%a_%%b.%%c"
)
```